# set model properties in view and then send it to controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can i set model properties in view and then send it to controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reject", "Maker", FormMethod.Get))
{
  <input type="submit" value="Reject" />
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._strRejectReason)
}
```

my model have 2 propeties first one is a string i sent it to controller successfully using the 
textbox the second one is int id which i want to set it in the view just like 
Model.id = item.Id; 
which item is a variable of the loop in each row 
how can i set the id without using the textbox to send the whole model object to controller

my controller :

```
public ActionResult Reject(MakerTransactions MakerTransactions)
{
   MakerCheckerUnitOfWorkBase _MakerCheckerUnitOfWorkBase = new  MakerCheckerUnitOfWorkBase();
   MakerTransactions.RouteAgentsConfigsMaker = _MakerCheckerUnitOfWorkBase.RouteAgentsConfigsChecker.RejectMaker(MakerTransactions.id,MakerTransactions._strRejectReason);

   return View(MakerTransactions);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be hidden:

```
@Html.Hidden("PropertyName", item.Id);
```

For textbox:

```
@Html.TextBox("PropertyName", item.Id);
```